# Qt C++ Creating a square audio tone wave. Play and saving it

Tags: c++, qt, math, audio, waveform

Good day experts I need guidance. 
I have a situation that is two part. 
Firstly, I need to generate a square wave audio tone for a specific time specified using Qt C++ and I'm completely lost on even where to start.

Secondly I also need to export the audio to a .wav or mp3. 
I read somewhere that I'll need to write WAV headers to the file before I can export the data. My second question is how to export the audio in the QBuffer to a wav file.

I have found the following project on Git.
However this generates a sine wave only and not a square wave. 
https://github.com/picaschaf/Soundgenerator

Looking at the function in this project

```
void QxtSoundGenerator::appendSound(qreal amplitude, float frequency, int msecs)
{

msecs = (msecs < 50) ? 50 : msecs;

qreal singleWaveTime = 1.0 / frequency;

qreal samplesPerWave = qCeil(format->sampleRate() * singleWaveTime);

quint32 waveCount = qCeil(msecs / (singleWaveTime * 1000.0));

quint32 sampleSize = static_cast<quint32>(format->sampleSize() / 8.0);

QByteArray data(waveCount * samplesPerWave * sampleSize * format->channelCount(), '\0');

unsigned char* dataPointer = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data.data());

for (quint32 currentWave = 0; currentWave < waveCount; currentWave++)
{
    for (int currentSample = 0; currentSample < samplesPerWave; currentSample++)
    {
        double nextRadStep = (currentSample / static_cast<double>(samplesPerWave)) * (2 * M_PI);

        quint16 sampleValue = static_cast<quint16>((qSin(nextRadStep) + 1.0) * 16383.0);

        for (int channel = 0; channel < format->channelCount(); channel++)
        {
            qToLittleEndian(sampleValue, dataPointer);
            dataPointer += sampleSize;
        }
    }
}

soundBuffer->append(data);
}
```

In the project you can append different frequencies then play them one after the other which is perfect. It just needs to be a Square wave.

Can someone please advice me as I'm not very good at math in this regard, or help me understand this block of code or show me how to go about creating a square wave in this fashion in Qt C++. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see `qSin(nextRadStep) + 1.0`. :)

Comment: Trying with `qSin(nextRadStep) + 1.0` doesn't produce sound unless i misinterpret your suggestion. I'm completely lost in the math

Comment: Do you want someone else to do their job ?, then hire someone, that's the part that makes the sinusoidal wave, you should read some of the dumb maths and try to transform that into sine wave to square: try with `quint16 sampleValue = static_cast<quint16>((qSin(nextRadStep)> 0 ? 1 : 0)*32767);`

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean to offend, I'm merely trying to learn and I find this particular issue a little confusing. I was looking in the wrong place thinking it would be the M_Pi being responsible for creating the wave. As per your last suggestion it seems to have produced a square wave. I removed the * 32767 and that's why it didn't produce any audio.  Thank you for assisting me.

Answer (score 1):

Like eyllanesc mentioned, you can take the sine wave generator and use the min value when below zero, and the max value when above zero. However one thing to note is that this will produce a naive square wave. This will have artifacts because you have value changes that are above the Nyquist limit. To get a better sound you should be looking to create a band-limited square wave. A band-limited square wave is produced by adding up sine wave harmonics that are below Nyquist.

Further reading:

Nyquist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate

Band limited Square waves: https://www.nayuki.io/page/band-limited-square-waves

Comment: Thank you for the information I'll have a look at the links provided.